# After Copying text from UITextView present in an UIView , UITextView is changed to UIWebDocumentView?

Tags: ios, uiview, uitextview, subview

I have placed `UITextView`, `UIButton` and `UIImageView` in an `UIView`. If I log `UIView Subviews` its shows all the three subviews correctly. But after selecting and copying text from `UITextView`, the logged  `UIView's` subViews is changed to `UIWebDocumentView`.

Any help is Appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

`UITextView` has various subviews, including a `UIWebDocumentView` that holds the text (or attributedText). You can see them when you log (you're probably already doing this for your main view):

```
for (UIView *subview in textView.subviews)
    NSLog(@"subview: %@", subview.description);
```

Of course, per Apple, we shouldn't be playing with those subviews. This is especially frustrating when subviews misbehave.

From the [UIView Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html):

> For complex views declared in UIKit and other system frameworks, any subviews of the view are generally considered private and subject to change at any time. Therefore, you should not attempt to retrieve or modify subviews for these types of system-supplied views. If you do, your code may break during a future system update.